# iOS CoreText CTLineGetStringRange with CTLineRef from CTLineCreateTruncatedLine

Tags: ios, core-text

I have the following code in iOS:

```
CFAttributedStringRef attributedString = ...
CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString);
CTLineRef truncatedLine = CTLineCreateTruncatedLine(line, 50.0, kCTLineTruncationEnd, NULL);

CFRange lineRange = CTLineGetStringRange(line);
CFRange truncatedLineRange = CTLineGetStringRange(truncatedLine);
```

My lineRange is the same as truncatedLineRange.  Why?  The documentation makes no mention of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [coretext-dev mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coretext-dev/), [this is expected behavior](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coretext-dev/2011/Apr/msg00006.html):

> The truncated string still covers the
>   original string range, it's just that
>   some glyph(s) have subsumed the
>   truncated characters. Besides, it
>   would be impossible to represent a
>   discontiguous string range as a
>   CFRange in the case of middle
>   truncation.